# using std::function::target correctly

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

Can anyone help me implement the function `test` below, so that it accepts any `Callable` and an `std::function` and returns `true` if the `std::function`'s target is the Callable? I have been trying various things, but none of them work all the time and I can't even figure out for any of them why they work for the cases that they do work.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int foo(int) {return 0;}
int faz(int) {return 0;}

struct {
    int operator()(int) {return 0;}
} bar, baz;

template<class F1, class F2>
bool
test(F1&& f1, std::function<F2> f2) {
    //return f2.template target<F1>() == f1;
    //return f2.template target<F2>() == &f1;
    //return *f2.template target<std::add_pointer_t<F1>>() == &f1;
    //return *f2.template target<std::add_pointer_t<F2>>() == &f1;
    //return *f2.template target<std::add_pointer_t<F1>>() == f1;
    //...
}

int main() {
    std::function<int(int)> f{foo};
    std::cout << test(foo, f) << std::endl;
    std::cout << test(faz, f) << std::endl;
    f = bar;
    std::cout << test(bar, f) << std::endl;
    std::cout << test(baz, f) << std::endl;
}
```

(http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11346a171199af81)

Comment: `f2.template target<std::decay_t<F1>>() == f1`. But it does not make sense for `bar` because `bar` has no operator==.

Comment: You need to be aware that std::function *copies* a functor object! A fact that already was very hard on my stomach in the past...

Comment: @Aconcagua so does that mean that I can't compare the address of the `target()` with the address of the object?

Comment: @baruch Exactly... And it means that you need to take care what you actually pass to the std:.function. Once had a (complex) class that *could* have been used as callback functor, if not copied, the copy broke the design. Needed a separate wrapper functor around a pointer/reference to the class then... As this was the case quite often in the project, wrote a template for.

Comment: @Aconcagua Did you consider `std::ref`?

Comment: @cpplearner Not in those days, was yet `std::tr1::function` then and `ref` was not yet available, but the copying did not change. Today, I'd use it for sure...

Comment: @cpplearner Thank you, that solved the issue, though I am now trying to figure out how/why that works. I can't select a comment as an answer...

Comment: @cpplearner by "that" I meant your first comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
template<class F1, class F2>
bool test(F1&& f1, std::function<F2> f2) {
  auto* ptr =  f2.template target<std::decay_t<F1>>();
  if (!ptr) return false;
  return *ptr == f1;
}
```

This won't work for lambdas, because lambdas have no `operator==`.

This won't work for your struct, because it has no `operator==`.

It will work for function pointers, because they do have an `operator==`.

```
struct bob {
  int operator()(int) {return 0;}
  bool operator==(bob const& o)const{return true;}
} bar, baz;
```

now it works.  Of course, both `bar` and `baz` compare equal to any `bob`.

Now, function stores a *copy* of anything you pass it.  So you cannot compare the address of the function stored in function to the address of the thing it copied from and get a useful result.

`std::ref` wraps a pointer up to act reference like.

Comment: Can you explain how this works? Why does `std::decay` solve the problem?

Comment: @bataxlch it is the actual type stored?  Read up on forwarding references and function pointer decay.

Comment: @baruch So, if function references "decay" to function pointers at the drop of a hat.  `std::function` stores a function pointer if you pass it a function reference.  Your code in `test` has a function reference `f`.  It asks `std::function` for that function reference, which does not exactly match the type.  If we decay `F`, we get the function pointer type.  This also strips off `const` and `volatile` if they are there (as `std::function` doesn't store `const` objects, it stores a non-`const` copy).

Comment: @acon `struct {
    int operator()(int) {return 0;}
}` is "your struct" in question (from OP).  It has no `operator==`.

Comment: @Aconcagua I do so by example right after the next paragraph.  ;)